# Generating complex Ruby class hierarchies from YAML

Tags: ruby, configuration, yaml

I'm looking for a generic mechanism for constructing configuration objects from a configuration file with multiple sections. Something like:

```
db:                           # key to section-specific config class
  adapter: sqlite3            # key to implementation-specific subclass
  database: ':memory:'        # ┐
  pool: 5                     # ├ implementation-specific key/value pairs
  timeout: 5000               # ┘

source:                       
  protocol: OAI
  oai_base_url: http://oai.example.org/oai
  metadata_prefix: some_prefix
  set: some_set
  seconds_granularity: true

index:
  adapter: solr
  url: http://solr.example.org/
  proxy: http://foo:bar@proxy.example.com/
  open_timeout: 120
  read_timeout: 300
  retry_503: 3
  retry_after_limit: 20
```

On reading this file, we'd create, e.g., a `DatabaseConfig` (specifically, a `Sqlite3Config`, that being a subclass of `DatabaseConfig`), a `SourceConfig` (specifically an `OAIConfig`), and an `IndexConfig` (specifically a `SolrConfig`).

Is an out-of-the-box way to do this without me having to write a bunch of `case/when` statements to map the different keys to different classes to be passed as arguments to `YAML.object_maker`?

Note: this is **not** a Rails application, but if the [Config gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/config) can be made to do something like this without too much hoop-jumping I'm open to it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that dynamically? To be able to use that classes in your app you need to know the class names at development time anyway. Why don't you want to have different config files for the different configurations: a `DB` class taking its configuration from a `db.yml`, the `Source` class getting the config from `source.yml`?

Comment: I don't want different config files because there's not enough configuration to justify different config files (the real app only has about as much configuration as you're looking at in the question). It's not that important to be able to go from `db:` to `DatabaseConfig` dynamically, but it is important to go from `sqlite3` to `Sqlite3Config` or `mysql` to `MysqlConfig` dynamically. Nothing outside of those subclasses needs to know about anything but `DatabaseConfig`, either at development time or run time.

Comment: (As for why try to go from `db:` to `DatabaseConfig` dynamically: DRY. It's basically the same operation as going from `sqlite3` to `Sqlite3Config`, and without it there's repetitive boilerplate in `DatabaseConfig`, `SourceConfig`, and `IndexConfig`. But I agree it's not as important, since clients of the config system do need to know those different sorts of things exist, even if they don't care about the specific implementation classes.)